# How to create a pixel perfect divider using css border

Tags: html, css, divider

I have a menu with background black and submenu with backgound grey.

Now I would like to have a pixel perfect divider between them.

But I have no idea what border color I should use to get pixel perfect divider. Can anyone help me?

Here is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="mainnav">
    <p> This is main nav </p>
</div>
<div class="subnav">
     <p> This is sub nav </p>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my css

```
.mainnav {
width:100%;
    height:60px;
    background-color:#000000;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-align:center;
}
.mainnav p {
padding-top:20px; 
}
.subnav p {
padding-top:10px; 
}
.subnav {
width:100%;
    height:45px;
    background-color:#333;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-align:center;
}
```

​

Here is my jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/ruUgk/

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about color choice

Comment: There is no direct solution to this. As others have said you need to use the right combination of colors. Here is a fiddle worth checking out. https://jsfiddle.net/larryeliemenye/shh0d4fp/15/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a bottom border to `.mainnav`

```
.mainnav {
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ruUgk/1/

Comment: That looks ugly. I'm asking something [like this](http://wbpreview.com/previews/WB0164888/). Check the header of that page

Comment: @user1091558 hire a web designer

Comment: @JFK Ah thanks but no thanks. I'm a student.. I'm learning.. So hiring a web designer not gonna help me.

Comment: actually @marissa is providing you with a good (ugly?) answer... you just have to choose the right color ... if we tell you what color, then you will learn nothing ... play around!

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you need any pixel perect devider! It is good as is. In any case, I do not think this site is for questions of this type, you should have a technical question here, not a question on how to make things look good.

Comment: Your answer is not exactly an answer. It just a comment. But you posted it as an answer. So if you have no intention in helping, then please stop answering like this.

Comment: Your question is not exactly a question either.

Answer (score 0):

I will add a dotted line between them

Add following line to mainnav css

```
border-bottom:1px dotted #fff;
```

Check this one on JSFiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/ruUgk/2/
```

Comment: Hello mate, I know how to use border like this. But i need pixel perfect borders like this. Check [this page header](http://wbpreview.com/previews/WB0164888/).